# PostGIS geography query returns a string value

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a strange issue. The lonlat column on my app works well on the development server –– its output is in the form of POINT(X Y). But when I move the data to the production server, the output is strange!

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `lon' for "0101000020E6100000541B9C887E7A52C02920ED7F80614440":String):

The lonlat value, which is encoded with SRID: 4326, is being read as a string. I am almost certain that there was a corruption in the data during migrating it from development to production because this was not a problem before the migration.

Does anyone know what about the database schema or column may cause this issue?

Comment: How are you moving the data between servers?    In the new server the column is still a geometry?   In your app how you read the column?

Comment: I am moving the data in two steps. First, I dump the schema of the database (`pg_dump --schema-only -C -c`) and restore that in the remote server using `psql`. Second, I dump out the data with `pg_dump --data-only -C` and do the same thing as above to restore it.

Comment: The lonlat column on the remote server is still typed `geometry(Point,4326)`.

Comment: I just remembered that I had done one other thing. Prior to moving the data, I killed all other connections to the server –– including the Rails app's connection. Not sure if that may have caused my problem. My sense is the schema search_path has something to do with this. If the postgis is not in the search path when the connection is re-established, the app cannot use postgis functions, right?

Comment: But locally when I kill the connections, the app seems to function normally. So...I'm still not sure what is happening.

Comment: do you have the postgis extension on that db?

Comment: To be specific, you are looking at a hex-encoded representation of [Well-known binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_binary). This is it's expected form.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, I have the extension enabled. I'm going to assume that it's working well. I was able to run a few queries on it from the console. That probably eliminates the data corruption hypothesis –– although I'm certain there is nothing wrong in the application layer, either. This is going to drive me nuts. I wish there was a way of rolling back my database state to an earlier state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when I killed the connection to the server to migrate the data, Rails did not set the schema search path (meaning didn't discover the postgis extension) upon reconnecting. I had to restart the server to solve this problem.

Comment: It is a good idea to install Postgis functions into template1, which ensures any new dbs will have them by default, and might avoid some of the issues you are seeing around search_paths.

Answer (score 0):

A geometry field stores its data as WKB. To see the WKT representation you need to change your query to something like

```
select ST_Astext(the_geom) as geometry from table
```

However, I don't know why in your development you have some kind of implicit conversion between WKB binary data and WKT strings. ¿What version of postgres and postgis are you using?

What lang is in your app server?

Is that ActiveRecord you're using?

Comment: Yes, it is ActiveRecord. I am using Ruby on Rails on my app server. It's deployed to Heroku. Could it be that postgis was not added to search_path? Because that's the only issue I am noticing, though I don't know why my data migration script would not export the search_path...

Comment: The PostGIS version is 2.1.2. The Postgresql version is 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try something like

```
float ST_X(geometry a_point);
```

To make sure you can read the data properly and determinate if problem is on the data field or somewhere else.

I also would try doing the `pg_dump` in a single step if you determinate the problem is with the geometry column.

You can use pg_dump with option

```
--exclude-table-data=reg_expresion_ _tablename_  
--exclude-table-data=schema.reg_expresion_ _tablename_
```

This will bring all the schema definition, but exclude the table data and bring only the data from table you need.